# GET request response on to Jade page?

Tags: node.js, http, express, get, pug

I've managed to make a GET request to an API however now I want to get the response on to a Jade page.
Here is my code for the GET request so far. This is in 'index.js' in the routes 'folder'. Any ideas about how I can get the response on to a Jade page?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
var url = 'http://data.police.uk/api/forces';

    http.get(url, function(res){
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            var response = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log("Successful")
        });

        }).on('error', function(e){
            console.log("Error: ", e);
        })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router

`res.render('viewName',{"variable":"value"});`

In your view

`p #{variable}`

Comment: Where does the router code go? And what do you mean by variable and value?

Comment: Sorry, the file you posted is your router. The code I posted is when your rendering the view, so you'd do it where you did res.send().

Comment: How what would I name the variable and what would the value be? That's what I'm most confused about

Comment: When you call render, your passing an object. In your view, you can use the values in that object. So you could do `p The value is #{value}` and the object you'd pass would look like `{"value":"some value"}`

Comment: For some reason, there's an error message which is that the object does not have a function called 'render'

Comment: Do you have `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to start from scratch, you should probably look at some sample templates for node.js with express.

http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/

This would tell you how to set up the structure of the app.